# Javascript Bookmarklet that opens image on click

Tags: javascript

Im trying to create a JS Bookmarklet that when a user clicks, an image opens up in an absolutely position div on the page there currently viewing only im not sure how.

I have the following

```
newDiv=document.createElement("div");
var img=document.createElement('img');
img.src='http://www.dannemann.com/images/lensflarePhilosophy.png';
newDiv.appendChild(img);
my_div=document.body("org_div1");
document.body.append(newDiv)
```

and ive tried compressiing it and adding Javascript: before it with no luck...

Comment: What, if anything, actually happens when you try your bookmarlet?

Comment: Nothing happens at all @David

Comment: If you use Firefox, have you tried dumping this in the JavaScript scratchpad (Shift+F4)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this (styling etc. is, ofcourse, all up to you, this is an example):

```
javascript:(function(){var newDiv,img;
if (!document.querySelector('#imgoverlay')){
 newDiv =  document.createElement("div");
 newDiv.id = 'imgoverlay';
 document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
 with (newDiv.style){
   position = 'absolute';
   top: '0';
   bottom = '0';
   left = '0';
   right = '0';
   textAlign = 'center';
 }
} else {
 newDiv = document.querySelector('#imgoverlay');
}
newDiv.innerHTML = '';
img = new Image();
img.style.margin = '0 auto';
img.style.verticalAlign = 'middle';
img.src ='http://www.dannemann.com/images/lensflarePhilosophy.png';
newDiv.appendChild(img);}())
```

It showed a bright sun here ;)

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are wrapping your code when you are making bookmarklets.

```
javascript:(function(){
   newDiv=document.createElement("div");
   var img=document.createElement('img');
   img.src='http://www.dannemann.com/images/lensflarePhilosophy.png';
   newDiv.appendChild(img);
   var bodyTag = document.getElementsByTagName('body') [0];
   bodyTag.appendChild(newDiv)
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

***More optimized version:***

```
(function(){var d=document.createElement('div');d.innerHTML='<img src=\'http://www.dannemann.com/images/lensflarePhilosophy.png\' />';d.setAttribute('style','position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;background:#666');document.body.appendChild(d);})()
```

Readable:

```
var d = document.createElement('div');
d.innerHTML = '<img src=\'http://www.dannemann.com/images/lensflarePhilosophy.png\' />';
d.setAttribute('style','position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;background:#666')
document.body.appendChild(d);
```

---

here you go:

```
(function(){var div=document.createElement('div');var a=div.style;div.innerHTML='<img src=\'http://www.dannemann.com/images/lensflarePhilosophy.png\' />';a.position='absolute';a.top=0;a.left=0;a.width='100%';a.height='100%';a.background='#666';document.body.appendChild(div);})()
```

Readable version:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
var a = div.style;
div.innerHTML = '<img src=\'http://www.dannemann.com/images/lensflarePhilosophy.png\' />';
a.position = 'absolute';
a.top = 0;
a.left = 0;
a.width = '100%';
a.height = '100%';
a.background = '#666';
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

---

Just some points:

- Like others said, the method is not `append` (`append` is for jQuery). it's `appendChild`.
- When you want to just nest some tags under your dynamically created `div` just use `innerHTML` of that `div`. no need to use `createElement` again.
- For long `style`s it's better to use `setAttribute`, since it's a bookmarklet and your code must consume as little space as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.appendChild()` (rather than `.append()`), i.e.

```
document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/GNMkV/).